# How to access Component state from <Component> body </Component> in other Component?

Tags: reactjs, state

I show a cool feature of react where Component state can be used from where it's body where it's being used.

Here is an example from firebase [Link](https://react-firebase-js.com/docs/react-firebase-realtime-database/getting-started)

```
<FirebaseDatabaseNode
    path="user_bookmarks/"
    limitToFirst={this.state.limit}
    orderByValue={"created_on"}
>
    {d => 
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <pre>Path {d.path}</pre>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }}
</FirebaseDatabaseNode>
```

In this example FirebaseDatabaseNode is Component and we're accessing d inside it.

I want to implement similar so I could access data of component in similar way. Here is my attempt to implement similar state access for Dashboard Component.

```
export default function Dashboard({
    children,
    user
}: {
    children: ReactNode;
    user: any
}) {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
    const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = React.useState(LinkItems[DEFAULT_SELECTED_ITEM])

//...
}
```

And I want to access selectedMenu inside of Dashboard in index.js

```
export default function () {

    return (
        <Dashboard user={user}>

            {selectedMenu => {
                return (
                    <div>{selectedMenu}</div>
                )
            }
            }
        </Dashboard>
    )
}
```

But this is not working in my case and I don't know the exact terminology.

Comment: For starters, your children prop has to be defined as `(typeof selectedMenu) => ReactNode`

Comment: Thanks for your help I have got the solution

Comment: Pattern/terminology is known as [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally while I explore the firebase source I found out that they are using [render-and-add-props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/render-and-add-props) Library.

Dashboard.js

```
import { renderAndAddProps } from 'render-and-add-props';
//...

export default function Dashboard({
    children,
    user
}: {
    children: ReactNode;
    user: any
}) {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
    const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = React.useState(LinkItems[DEFAULT_SELECTED_ITEM])

    //...


    return (

        <div>
        //...

            // for rendering element with props
            {renderAndAddProps(children, { 'selectedMenu': selectedMenu })}

        </div>

    )
}
```

//in index

```
export default function () {

    return (
        <Dashboard user={user}>

            {({selectedMenu}) => { //                            {({ selectedMenu }: { selectedMenu: LinkItemProps }) if you're using typescript.

                return (
                    <div>{selectedMenu}</div>
                )
            }
            }
        </Dashboard>
    )
}
```